# Redirect to another html in angularjs webpage reloads controller

Tags: angularjs

In my html page, clicking a row sends you to another html page. ng-click calls the funtion showScripts and fills the variable $scope.Scripts using ajax call, which I am using in this new html page.

```
$scope.showScripts=function(event,item){
     $http.get('/Scripts/'+item).success(
    function(data) {
      $scope.Scripts = data.responseData;
    });

       if (event.ctrlKey) {
                window.open("/scripts.html","_blank"); // in new tab
            } else {
                window.open('/Scripts.html',"mywindow"); // in new tab
            }


  }
```

The File Scripts.html is using the same controller. So when the html loads, the angularjs file loads again and the values in $scope.Scripts go back to undefined.  Can I prevent the controller from refreshing the values?

Comment: ok,that seems a better option but I have to share the value that is clicked to the controller. If i use a service to do that, will the service retain the value ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use this logic:

```
var yourUrl = '/scripts.html';
$window.location.href = yourUrl;
```

OR:

```
$window.location.href = '/scripts.html';
$window.location.reload();
```

Answer (score 0):

when you are using same controller for different views, you can create Service or factory method for storing and retrieving data. Another way is that you can store the data in $rootScope as well.